Can the Fourier transform of a test function vanish on an interval?
Suppose $f$ is a test function and thus compactly supported on some set $S$.
Its Fourier transform is
\begin{equation}
\widehat{f}(p) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{ipx} f(x) \, .
\end{equation}
Is it possible for this Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ to vanish on some interval $(a,b)$?
I have tried a number of things and believe that this should not be possible, also with regard to this question. More generally, is this possible if $f$ is a Schwartz function?
I would also appreciate if anyone could direct me to a general discussion of the relation between the support of a function and that of its Fourier transform.

Regarding your last paragraph, A function and its Fourier transform cannot both be compactly supported

Thank you for the link. While I had seen this result I still asked the question since compact support for f is a more stringent condition than vanishing within some interval.

Of course not. Since $f$ has compact support, then $\hat{f}$ is the restriction to $R$ of  a function which is analytic in the whole complex plane (ie an entire function). It cannot be identically 0 on an interval (principle of isolated zeros) if $f$ is not zero almost everywhere.

I didnt know that. Do you have a link? (That the fourier transform of a compact support schwarz function is analytic).

@lalala https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley–Wiener_theorem

Paley-Wiener does not seem necessary: a simple power expansion around $z$ is easily proved to have a positive radius on convergence.

additionaly with was already said, the reason an entire function descrived by a power series cannot become some constant value on an interval, like the value zero, is due the Identity Theorem

Concerning the Schwartz class the Fourier transform is an isomorphism from  $\cal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ onto itself. As $\cal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ contains functions with compact support, the answer is yes.

I don't quite follow why the isomorphism property (as inner product spaces I assume) implies the result. It could be that all images of compact support functions do not have the desired property.

We have $f\in S$ iff $\widehat{f}\in S.$ I have added a link in my answer.

The question in OP: "Does there exist a nonzero function in $S$ so that its Fourier transform vanishes on some interval ?" The answer is yes. The answer is no for functions with compact support.

Thank you, that does indeed answer the question.

Does not test functions always have compact-support?
